# Sechna Architect Xcode was not found, please specify it

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, xcode5, ios-simulator, sencha-architect

I am using sencha architect with the following version information.

```
 version:3.0.3.1382
 channel:3.0.1-stable
 platform:1.3.0.803
 cmd:4.0.3.74
 framework:Sencha Touch 2.3.x
```

I am trying to simulate the app on IOS simulator and I keep getting the error "Xcode was not found, please specify it".

Also I am using mac os version : 10.9.2 & XCode Version : 5.1 (5B130a)

My IOS Simulator is found in location :

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications

Could anyone please help me out in resolving this issue ?.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with the same settings Here is the recent discussion on the [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282613-Architect-3.0.2-quot-Xcode-was-not-found-Please-specify-it-quot) Hopefully there will be a patch soon